# How to override a variable value with TamperMonkey when the function is inside a script within the HTML

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

**The Problem**

I have the following function **export** called from the  found inside the HTML page before

```
 <input class="print" type="button" value="EXPORT" onclick="export()">
```

I want to modify the value **50000** to a greater value like **100000** and also the alert message with TamperMonkey, but can't figure out how to do it until now

```
<script>

  function export() {
    var ssrt=$('#minrng').val();
    if(ssrt==''||ssrt==undefined){
        alert("Please enter the minimum range");
        return false;
    }
    var maxlength=$('#maxrng').val();
    if(maxlength==''|| maxlength==undefined){
        alert("Please enter the maximium range");
        return false;
    }
    if(maxlength > 50000){
        alert("The range should be less than 50000");
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

**What I've done until now:**

I have tried the following script to override the value **50000** with TamperMonkey, but the value is still the same
And how to change the alert message if the value has been changed successfully?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
   location.href="javascript:(function(){ window.maxlength = 100000; })()"
   unsafeWindow.maxlength = 100000;
   Window.maxlength = 100000;
  })();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind, that export is a reserved word. (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correct, you want to update the number 50000 in `if(maxlength > 50000){…`, not `maxlength` itself. So you shouldn't try to change `maxlength`, but the number. You can change the script element with something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML.replace(/50000/g,'100000');
```

You may have to write a loop before and search through all script elements to find the correct one to change.

Comment: Exactly that's the result I want to achieve, unfortunately, it's not modified and the value is still 50000

Comment: I noticed that it didn't replace globally, now I've changed `replace('50000','100000)` with `replace(/50000/g,'100000')`.
If that doesn't help, you might want to check, if you are modifying the right script node.